# systemlog message: "Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com" - what does it mean and what should I do about it?

Tags: syslog, whoopsie

When running "tail -f /var/log/syslog" in the terminal I keep getting the message: "Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com"

```
Oct  2 15:06:22 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 systemd[1746]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Oct  2 15:06:22 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 tracker-extract[20772]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Oct  2 15:06:22 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 tracker-extract[20772]: Setting priority nice level to 19
Oct  2 15:06:23 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 dbus-daemon[1758]: [session uid=1000 pid=1758] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract'
Oct  2 15:06:23 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 systemd[1746]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Oct  2 15:06:33 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 systemd[1746]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Oct  2 15:06:53 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 tracker-store[20691]: OK
Oct  2 15:06:53 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 systemd[1746]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Oct  2 15:09:06 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 systemd[1746]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Oct  2 15:10:01 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 CRON[21006]: (duncan) CMD (rsync -av --delete --exclude /.cache/* --exclude snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Cache --exclude /.local/share/* --exclude={/GabAI/*,/deja-dup/*,/mozilla/firefox/*}  /home/duncan/ /media/duncan/Rsync2/Home-duncan/)
Oct  2 15:12:25 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages...
Oct  2 15:12:25 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 systemd[1]: ua-messaging.service: Succeeded.
Oct  2 15:12:25 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages.
Oct  2 15:13:57 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 whoopsie[1430]: [15:13:57] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct  2 15:13:57 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 whoopsie[1430]: [15:13:57] offline
Oct  2 15:13:58 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 whoopsie[1430]: [15:13:58] online
Oct  2 15:15:04 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 whoopsie[1430]: [15:15:04] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct  2 15:15:04 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 whoopsie[1430]: [15:15:04] offline
Oct  2 15:15:05 duncan-IdeaCentre-K430 whoopsie[1430]: [15:15:05] online
^C
```

What does this mean and what should I do about it?

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1367026/edit) your question to show us the entire relevant line(s) of the syslog.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and time. I have edited my question - I hope it is satisfactory but it looks like too much data to me. Sorry if this is the case, I'm not very tech savvy.

Answer (score 6):

Your Ubuntu system was trying to send a crash report, but your system was offline at that moment.

The chain of event is typically this:

1. One of your system's applications or services crashes.
2. Your system detects the crash and triggers the `apport` application.
3. `apport` collects information about the crash, and saves it to a file in /var/crash. They are text files -- feel free to open and read them.
4. The `whoopsie` service detects a new .crash file, and attempts to send the file to the daisy.canonical.com server.
5. At daisy, similar reports are aggregated. You can see the result at http://errors.ubuntu.com. Those error statistics help set developer work priorities.

Step 4 generated the syslog events because a network connection is needed for the whoopsie-daisy connection. It's possible that daisy was briefly inaccessible or down for maintenance. Whoopsie will keep trying until it succeeds. If your syslog doesn't have whole scrolling pages of failed connection attempts, it's likely already succeeded and you're looking back in time.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation.
I shall work on it (as indicated - I am not tech "savvy" - and will see what I can do and report back.
Thanks once again for your very kind attention.

Comment: @Duncan big edit. Check the timestamp on the syslog events -- you might be looking at a historic event instead of a current problem.

Comment: I have accessed my /var/crash dir and found this in the file under it:
-------------------------------
Date 29 Sept 08h00
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
Date: Wed Sep 29 08:10:06 2021
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 20.04
ExecutablePath: /opt/dissenter.com/dissenter/dissenter
ExecutableTimestamp: 1584909200
ProcCmdline: /opt/dissenter.com/dissenter/dissenter
ProcCwd: /home/duncan
ProcEnviron: 
ProcMaps:
-------------------- 
Is there anything you can suggest I fix?

Comment: Well, now you know what crashed. If you open the file, it will tell an expert exactly why it crashed in exquisite, lengthy technical detail. Note that "*How do I fix the cause of this crash*?" is not the question you asked, so it's not the question I answered. You might be able to fix it; you might not. Usually not, unless you are an expert with the codebase of that application.

Comment: Sadly, I'm no expert!
Perhaps you could tell me how to correct the fact that my pc / system is not able to access daisy (as in "Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com"
Many thanks again for your time and expertise.

Comment: Is your system online? Did you try pinging daisy.ubuntu.com? You seem to be in the area of basic network troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, I am online.
I pinged "daisy.ubuntu.com" but got no return; yet, am able to successfully ping google.com (indicating that I am online).

Comment: Just as an FYI: daisy.ubuntu.com doesn't seem to respond to ping, even though the service is obviously up if you visit https://daisy.ubuntu.com/ (you'll get the message `Invalid BSON.`, but you are talking to the service so it's up).

You can safely ignore the `offline` messages as long as they are followed by an `online` message soon after, indicating that the retry did its job.